# Writing to I/O Port Controller driver (inpout) (PS/2 Keyboard port) Left and Right keyboard keypresses?

Tags: c++, io, keyboard, hardware-interface, ioports

I'm using `inpout32/64` Hardware I/O Port Controller using this system driver [InpOut32 and InpOutx64](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/inpout32)

I'm trying to use this to bypass problems I have with DirectInput games.
(Can't use `SendInput`, because it will reject inputs without a very long sleep delays, and I can't wait that long it has to be very fast keyboard inputs).

I currently got `inpout32` working for mostly all my keyboard keys, I can't figure out how to access LEFT/RIGHT arrow keys.

By looking at this webpage about PS/2 Keyboard [PS/2 Keyboard commands](http://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard)

Figured out this is what I need

```
0xE0, 0x4B   cursor left pressed
0xE0, 0x4D   cursor right pressed
```

How do I send both of those, I don't understand what is that `0xE0` i'm guessing it's the scan code and the `0x4B` and `0x4D` are the positions in that scan code, but it's not working in my example it keeps sending the `\` for the LEFT key.

Here is the code I'm using

```
BOOL isDriverOn = false;
#define LEFT 0x4B 
#define RIGHT 0x4D 

void setup() {
        isDriverOn = IsInpOutDriverOpen();
}

//void  _stdcall Out32(short PortAddress, short data);
//short _stdcall Inp32(short PortAddress);
void DD_PS2command(short comm, short value) {
        if(!isDriverOn) {
            printf("PS/2 Keyboard port driver is not opened\n");
            return;
        }
        //keyboard wait.
        int kb_wait_cycle_counter = 1000;
        while((Inp32(0x64) & 0x02) && kb_wait_cycle_counter--) //wait to get communication.
            Sleep(1);
        if(kb_wait_cycle_counter) { //if it didn't timeout.
            Out32(0x64, comm); //send command
            kb_wait_cycle_counter = 1000;
            while((Inp32(0x64) & 0x02) && kb_wait_cycle_counter--) //wait to get communication.
                Sleep(1);
            if(!kb_wait_cycle_counter) {
                printf("failed to get communication in cycle counter timeout), who knows what will happen now\n");
                //return false;
            }
            Out32(0x60, value); //send data as short
            Sleep(1);
            //return true;
        } else {
            printf("failed to get communication in counter timeout, busy)\n");
            //return false;
        }
}

void DD_Button(short btn, bool release = false, int delay = 0)
{
  //0xE0, 0x4B   {Left}
  //0xE0, 0x4D   {Rght}
  //return scode | (release?0x80:0x00);
  short scan_code = 0;
  if(btn == LEFT)
      scan_code = LEFT + 0xE0;
  else if(btn == RIGHT)
      scan_code = RIGHT + 0xE0;
  else
      scan_code = 0x0;

  scan_code |= (release ? 0x80 : 0x00);

  if(delay)  
    Sleep(delay);
  DD_PS2command(0xD2, scan_code);
}
```

**EDIT:** Problem is solved, this below function works, just need to make DD_PS2command return true/false (to indicate if it went through or not).
New problem it releases the key instantly it doesn't hold the key down.

Here are all the keys http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/scancodes1.html

```
void DD_Button(short btn, bool release = false, int delay = 0)
{
  //;0xE0, 0x4B      {Left}
  //;0xE0, 0x4D      {Rght}
  //  return scode | (release? 0x80: 0x00)
  short scan_code = 0;
  bool good = false;
  switch(btn) {
    case LEFT:
    case RIGHT:
        scan_code = btn;
        //send extended byte first (grey code)
        good = DD_PS2command(0xD2, 0xE0);
        break;
  }
  printf("good = %d\n", good);
  scan_code |= (release ? 0x80 : 0x00);

  if(delay)  
    Sleep(delay);
  //0xD2 - Write keyboard output buffer
  good = DD_PS2command(0xD2, scan_code);
  printf("2 good = %d\n", good);
}
```

Comment: The last link is broken (the whole www.computer-engineering.org site is broken (the domain expired)). Some alternatives are (essentially the ***same content by the same author***, but slightly different titles and modification dates): *[The PS/2 Mouse/Keyboard Protocol](https://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/PS2%20Keyboard.pdf)* (2003-05-09), *[The PS/2 Keyboard Interface](http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/nios_devices/datasheets/PS2%20Keyboard%20Protocol.htm)* (2003-04-01), and *[The AT-PS/2 Keyboard Interface](https://www.tayloredge.com/reference/Interface/atkeyboard.pdf)* (2001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0xE0` is an escape code for extended keys - i.e. for left, you send `0xE0`, then send `0x4B` immediately afterwards.

Comment: Yes this solved my problem, any idea why it releases the key instantly after it sends? or.. there is something I need to send to make it not release?